# Mouse won't work on USB switch

Tags: usb, mouse

I've tried 2 USB switches, [Rybozen USB switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M66SD79) and [Takya USB swtich](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W7H6GNK), and my mouse will not work when I switch over to my [HP EliteDesk 705 G4 Mini PC](https://www.newegg.com/hp-elitedesk-705-g4/p/1VK-001E-3VC41?Item=9SIAA0SAM71191).

The switches worked fine on a Mac laptop I once had and it works fine on my [Lenovo ThinkPad P50](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-p/ThinkPad-P50/p/22TP2WPWP50).

I've tried two mice.  My [Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000A6PPOK) works fine on both switches across all machines.

It would seem it is something w/ my HP machine but what could it be?  And how I can track down more details so I can reach out to the appropriate support people?

**Workaround:** every time I switch to the HP machine I have to unplug & re-plug the mouse to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the USB switches use USB-A ports, and USB-A to USB-A cables, for connecting to the computers.  [This violates the USB spec](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/444287/279177), and quite blatantly so.  This is a sign of poor engineering and a low quality product.  I suspect that there is nothing wrong with your computers and everything wrong with these USB switches.  Considering the similarity of the two products it's likely they contain the same electronics but just in different cases.  My suggestion is to open up your wallet a bit wider and buy a quality USB switch from a trusted brand.

Comment: [they almost all work this way](https://www.amazon.com/usb-switch/s?k=usb+switch), weird

Comment: @spottedmahn  Indeed, they do.  This is unfortunate as I suspect a great many of these are sold and then end up in the trash, it's just not worth people's time to complain about a $20 device that doesn't work as advertised.  Amazon has no motivation to fix this unless people complain as they profit from selling this junk too.  A few years ago Amazon did some house cleaning on junk USB products because people complained of USB power supplies destroying expensive phones, USB-C cables starting fires, etc.  It seems that USB junk is taking over Amazon again and they need to clean house once more.

Comment: I found this thread today because I've got the same problem with another (but similar) USB switch. I don't think I've ever seen one that I would describe as "quality" or from a "trusted brand" and I'm curious about how they would differ. Should we look for switches with USB-C on the switch end? Or on both ends? Or what interface would be ideal here?